# Change the duration of multiple images vegas

Tags: vegas-pro

I have 5 different video files on my timeline and I want to make every one of them to be only 5 seconds long. Basically squeeze each of them to be 5 seconds long each.

I am using Vegas 13, but before when I used premiere I had the option when I right clicked the video in the timeline called "Speed/duration". Is there something similar to this in Vegas?

Comment: Are these images or videos? Do you just want to trim or change speed as well? Are their current lengths different from each other?

Comment: @Mulvya these are videos, I just want to change the speed so the video will be a specific length and yes the lengths are different but they are mostly 6-8 seconds each.

Comment: So, if you want to keep the same in-point, press down `Ctrl` and trim from the out-point till you achieve desired duration,

Comment: @Mulvya The problem is, I'll have over 100 clips, and doing it by hand dosen't seem like a smart move.

Comment: Doing it this once won't take that long. If you have to do it regularly, then, yes, you need an automation control.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm making a gym transformation video, so at the start i have two photos of 2 different posed myself side by side, and then the same for the next month, I want them to be exactly a certain time frame, doing it individually seems kind of annoying, is there anywhere i can type in the number of seconds i want the two photos for each month to appear?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the speed of multiple clips - find a script that does this. Vegas Pro supports scripting and there a lot of different scripts out there, both free and commercial. For example, [this one](http://vegasaur.com/rocket-speed) (commercial) can do this (enter the desired duration to  **Duration** control).